# Image gallery in php: Pause reading of array of files, continue onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, lazy-loading, auto-generate

I need to build an image-gallery which:

1. displays thumbnails auto-generated from large-image-directory, (done.)
2. has no browser-default scrollbars (replaced by Perfect Scrollbar), (done.)
3. has images in columns in equal width thumbnails, (done.)
4. displays new images in large-directory first, (done.)
5. lazy loading of thumbnails. (problem!)
6. has smooth scrolling like on smart phones (not reached because of 5).

A potential endless display of blocks of thumbnails (links to another page for the large-images) or as much as someone wants to scroll down. Gallery will have at least 1000-2000 thumbnail-links.

I understand that loading so many thumbnails at once might crash the browser and that's why I was trying to get the images to load lazilym, but for the life of me, I cannot get any lazy load plugin to work for my website. I tried it after removing perfect-scollbar from code but still no cigar. After a lot of searching I have to come to a conclusion that lazy load "might" not always work.

So I figure that I have to limit the number of thumbnails being loaded on the page to lets say 30. But at the same time, I want a link which will load another 30 images on the same page without reloading the page...

I am producing the code under this as it is before adding lazy load image plugin.

```
<head>
    <link href="src/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script src="src/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $('#Default').perfectScrollbar({ wheelSpeed: 50, wheelPropagation: true, minScrollbarLength: 20 });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
    .contentHolder { position:relative; margin:0px auto; padding:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
    .contentHolder .content {}
    .spacer { text-align:center }

    html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color:black;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .imagecontainer { width:100%; }

    #videos { width:100%; height:120px; } 

    #photos {
        line-height: 0;
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-gap:0px;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-gap:0px;
        column-count:5;
        column-gap:0px;
        float:left;
    }

    #photos img {
        /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
        width: 99% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        opacity:0.8;
        filter:alpha(opacity=80);
        -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
        transition: all 500ms ease;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    #photos img:hover { 
        width: 100% !important;
        opacity:1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    </style>

<div style="position:fixed; z-index:4; width:100%; background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.5)">Simple Menu Bar-Currently empty.</div>
<div id="Default" class="contentHolder">
    <div class="content">
    <section id="photos">

    <?php

    /* Get Directory with Dates Last Modified */

    function getimageswithdates(){
    $directory="preload-images/"; 
    $sortOrder="newestFirst"; 

    $results = array(); 
    $handler = opendir($directory); 

    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != "robots.txt" && $file != ".htaccess"){ 
            $currentModified = filectime($directory."/".$file); 
            $file_names[] = $file; 
            $file_dates[] = $currentModified; 
        } 
    } 

    closedir($handler); 

    //Sort the date array by preferred order 
    if ($sortOrder == "newestFirst"){ 
        arsort($file_dates); 
    } else { 
        asort($file_dates); 
    } 

    //Match file_names array to file_dates array 
    $file_names_Array = array_keys($file_dates); 
    foreach ($file_names_Array as $idx => $name) $name=$file_names[$name]; 
    $file_dates = array_merge($file_dates); 

    //Loop through dates array, save list to array and echo the list 
    $filelist = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($file_dates as $file_dates){ 
        $date = $file_dates; 
        $j = $file_names_Array[$i]; 
        $file = $file_names[$j]; 
        $i++; 
        $filelist[] = $file;
        echo '<a href="color.php?see='.str_ireplace(".jpg", " ", "$file"). '" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery">
        <img src="preload-images-thumbs/'.$file.'"  /></a>'; 
        }
    echo '</section> </div>';
    }

    /** settings **/
    $images_dir = 'preload-images/';
    $thumbs_dir = 'preload-images-thumbs/';
    $thumbs_width = 200;

    /* function:  generates thumbnail */
    function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width) {
    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);
    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);
    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
    }

    /** generate photo gallery **/
    $image_files = get_files($images_dir);
    if(count($image_files)) {
        $index = 0;
        foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
            $index++;
            $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
            if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
                $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
                if($extension) { make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width); } 
            } 
        }
    }
    else { }

    /* function:  returns files from dir */
    function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg')) {
        $files = array();
        if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
                if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
                    $files[] = $file; }
            }
        closedir($handle);
        }
        return $files;
    }

    /* function:  returns a file's extension */
    function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
    }

    echo getimageswithdates();

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

--------------------- EDIT -------------------

The foreach loop

```
$filelist = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($file_dates as $file_dates){ 
    $date = $file_dates; 
    $j = $file_names_Array[$i]; 
    $file = $file_names[$j]; 
    $i++; 
    $filelist[] = $file;
    echo '<a href="color.php?see='.str_ireplace(".jpg", " ", "$file"). '" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery">
    <img src="preload-images-thumbs/'.$file.'"  /></a>'; 
    }
```

Can the loop pause if i == 30, then resume on click, and cycle in 30s?

Comment: This is a lot of code to wade through.  Can you boil it down to just 10 or 20 lines that need to change?

Comment: Done. Please scroll down to "Edit"

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, do XHR (ajax) to achieve this, send the appropriate parameters from javascript to the php so it loops in specific range that you want.

Comment: Reading up on it. Thank you :)